# When does definite article denote possesion?

Tags: definite-article

> die kirche des allmächtigen gottes

I read the above as "The church the almighty god" but if you plug this into google translate, you get:

> The Church of Almighty God

Now, why does 'des' mean of here?

Comment: It's a good idea to use proper capitals avoid confusion. Both *Kirche* and *Gottes* are nouns so they are capitalized in German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"des" is simply the genitive form of the definite article "der/die/das", and German encodes possession/attribution between noun phrases as a genitive. English does the same, but since there are (almost) no nominal inflections left, prepositions are used as case hints ('of' hints at a genitive function, 'to' at a dative). Therefore, "A des B" (or "A der B" if B is feminine or plural) usually corresponds to "A of B".

Comment: German can also use the article where English leaves it out, especially with the genitive. That said, I don't think using an article with *Gott* is that common, as least for monotheists. But an article is generally needed when you'd use one in English.

Comment: An article is commonly used with _Gott_ when prefixed with an adjective. "Kirche Gottes" but "Kirche des allmächtigen Gottes", "Geist Gottes" but "Geist des lebendigen Gottes" and so on.